# Binding a tree view structure , in asp .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have tried to create a asp,net treeview structure using below

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head runat="server">
     <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TreeView
            ID="TreeView1"
            runat="server" />    
    </div>
</form>
```

And in Code behind

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            PopulateTreeView();
    }
    private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        DataTable treeViewData = GetTreeViewData();
        AddTopTreeViewNodes(treeViewData);

    }
    private DataTable GetTreeViewData()
    {
        string selectCommand = "SELECT top 10 idx_client,idx_branch,client_name FROM tbl_client";
        string conString =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
        SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, conString);
        DataTable dtblDiscuss = new DataTable();
        dad.Fill(dtblDiscuss);
        return dtblDiscuss;
    }

    private void AddTopTreeViewNodes(DataTable treeViewData)
    {
        DataView view = new DataView(treeViewData);
        foreach (DataRowView row in view)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(row["client_name"].ToString(), row["idx_client"].ToString());
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
            newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            AddChildTreeViewNodes(treeViewData, newNode);
        }

    }

    private void AddChildTreeViewNodes(DataTable treeViewData, TreeNode parentTreeViewNode)
    {
        DataView view = new DataView(treeViewData);
        foreach (DataRowView row in view)
        {
            TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(row["client_name"].ToString(), row["idx_client"].ToString());
            parentTreeViewNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
            newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
            AddChildTreeViewNodes(treeViewData, newNode);
        }
    }
```

But it gives an Exception

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Please point out what are the changes needed, because am using this treeview for the first time
How i will solve the exception. Could any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your recursive call in `AddChildTreeViewNodes`:

```
private void AddChildTreeViewNodes(DataTable treeViewData, TreeNode parentTreeViewNode)
{
    DataView view = new DataView(treeViewData);
    foreach (DataRowView row in view)
    {
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode(row["client_name"].ToString(), row["idx_client"].ToString());
        parentTreeViewNode.ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
        newNode.PopulateOnDemand = true;
        // error caused by recursion below
        AddChildTreeViewNodes(treeViewData, newNode); // calls itself again REMOVE THIS
    }
}
```

What is happening here is that you are inserting a child node of your view and then try to insert another child node within it (which in turn will do the same thing). This will keep on happening until the stack is blown.

I suspect that you really don't need the line that I have marked as `REMOVE THIS`